# Grouping/Windowing in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

In the below image the first is the table(script provided) in question and 2nd is the expected output.
In column C we have different items like T1,T2,T3 and the records will be available in groups, T1 records  and then T2 or T3. there should not be any gap between those, T1 will start and finish and then only T2 item can appear. But if T1 is reappearing after other items, i want to consider it differently. What are the options to achieve the result in hive/spark?

I tried with rank in one column and then next value in other columns and tried to run some comparisons, but that did not help.

Any pointers please

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_A (A STRING, B STRING, C STRING);

INSERT INTO TEST_A (A, B, C) VALUES ('a','1-Jan','T1'), ('a','2-Jan','T1'),('a','3-Jan','T2'),('a','4-Jan','T3') ,('a','5-Jan','T1'),('a','6-Jan','T1')
```

Comment: So in expected result you always expect only 3 rows?
Can you give more information what should be in columns B-First, B-Last, Repeat-First, Repeat-Last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gap-and-islands problem.  I am going to propose putting each "island" of adjacent rows into a separate row.

One approach -- that works in this case -- is to use the difference of row numbers:

```
select a, c, min(b), max(b)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by a, c order by b) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by a, c, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

You can pivot this into multiple columns if you really want.  However, I think that just confuses the problem, because you may not know how many groups there are for a given `a`/`c` combination.